# Why 10% CPU when sleep() on Pi 1B

Tags: pigpio, c, performance

I'm writing a simple application in C to handle switching relays on an old Pi 1B. When the Pi is supposed to wait for the next action to handle, I use the `sleep()` system call. I checked with `top`, only to find out that my application still uses 10% CPU! Why?? So I tried to rewrite the code using `alarm()` and `pause()`. Of course the same: 10% CPU. Again: why??

Is there a way to put the process really to sleep, 0% CPU? Tips maybe?

Proof of a simple application using 10%:
[image]

```
#include <json-c/json.h>
#include <json-c/json_util.h>

main() {
    gpioInitialise();
    sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: We need the source code of a simple example of your application which uses 10%.

Comment: `sleep` pauses execution of a process, but the original process may have spawned other processes, and these child processes won't necessarily pause. You may have to pause at the "kernel level" to reach your objective; [here's a paper discussing some ways to do that](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html)

Comment: In the sample C-program above nothing is forked (by me), only a library is initialised and that seems to be enough to cause a constant 10% CPU load on a Raspberry Pi 1B. My objective is not to put the whole system in sleep-mode, just the process will do. I bet that if I remove the gpioInitialise() call the load will drop to <1%...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adopted a different library, and CPU utilisation during the sleep() call went down to 0: libgpiod to the rescue! It might not be the best gpio library around but at least there's no overhead in my case.
Sample: https://www.ics.com/blog/gpio-programming-exploring-libgpiod-library

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pigpio this is normal behaviour.

pigpio uses about 10% of 1 CPU to do the DMA sampling of GPIO and the generation of PWM.  This is a constant overhead when using pigpio.

Comment: Thanks, it's what crossed my mind. Obvious questions: are there other libraries that do not use 10% CPU? Or can I tell pigpio somehow not to sample when I don't need it? The thing is supposed to do nothing...